# iOS - UITableView reloadData after delay

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delay, reloaddata

I'm trying to create a UITablView extension function to reload table after some time delay, like:

```
extension UITableView {
    func reloadData(afterDelay delayTime: TimeInterval) -> Void {
        self.perform(#selector(self.reloadData), with: nil, afterDelay: delayTime)
    }
}
```

But it's showing me an error: **Ambiguous use of 'reloadData'**

What's its proper solution?

Here is snapshot with error message
[image]

Comment: Change your method name to something else like reloadDataWithDelay and check

Comment: If the purpose of the delay is to wait for some asynchronous task **don't do that**.

Comment: @vadian, you are absolutely right, and I need this function for same purpose. I've some animation operations, that needs tableview to wait for few time interval, to reload its data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename your function because it conflicts with UITableView's `reloadData()`

```
//---------
extension UITableView {

    // Default delay time = 0.5 seconds
    // Pass delay time interval, as a parameter argument
    func reloadDataAfterDelay(delayTime: TimeInterval = 0.5) -> Void {
        self.perform(#selector(self.reloadData), with: nil, afterDelay: delayTime)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this using a block, like so:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayTime) { [weak self] in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  extension UITableView {
    func reloadDataAfterDelay(delayTime: TimeInterval) -> Void {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delayTime
       DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {
           self.reloadData()
       }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You're going to want a `[weak self]` at the start of the block or this won't compile.

Comment: Now that you've removed the `self?` this may cause memory leaks

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
extension UITableView {
    func reloadDataWithDelay(delayTime: TimeInterval) -> Void {
        let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + 2
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime) {
             self.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 'reloadData' conflicts with its default method